# How to add reference in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My first ASP.NET Core project.

I'm getting an error

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Used NuGet to add reference to Entity Framework Core. I believe that should have fixed it, but no luck.

As you can see, the lib is listed under the `Dependencies` node instead of the usual `References` node, if that matters. I've compared the csproj files and nothing stands out as obvious why one has a references node and the other doesn't.

[image: Add reference?]

Comment: You appear to have a lot of warnings about various dependencies - have you looked into those warnings?

Comment: Maybe you should replace System.Data.Entity with the right namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore...

Comment: @BWhite EF Core is added as a NuGet package, not a reference. The namespace is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, not `System.Data.Entity`. Are you following an EF tutorial instead of an EF Core tutorial perhaps? Remove the explicit reference and change the namespace

Comment: Use "Clean solution", and maybe restart VS after cleaning.

Comment: @Archer this is a question about ASP.NET Core

Comment: @BWhite the [EF Core Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/) tutorials show how to add the proper package and use the correct namespaces. The examples never use `System.Data.Entity`

Comment: Adding the right namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The tutorial left me with TodoItems.ToListAsync undefined.

Comment: @Nikolaus Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .net the Namespace for EntityFramework is System.Data.Entity, but that changed for EF Core:
The right namespace is now Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore so

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

should fix it.